Can cv joint be damaged with rubber mallet hammer?
I went to discount tire bought 4 new tires. My truck doesn't have a lot of miles. (62k) Never been in car accident or any type. I work from home so technically is only use for small errands or when traveling which is not often. Truck had no issues. I went to replaced the tires and I sit where the window is to see the cars. I saw one of them hit the 1 old tire 3 times with force with a rubber mallet hammer just to get it "out". At the moment it was whatever but weird because you only use your bare hands to take it out (like changing it to a spare tire) but maybe it was a little bit "stuck" idk. Point is I got my truck back and starting making bunch of noises especially the turns. I bend down to see and I see cv joint leaking ONLY from the tire that was hit because they only hit one. I didnt go back the same day because they gave me the truck when closing up. I go back the following day complaining, they obviously say tires dont make noises but I ask them if there's a possibility that they damaged the cv joint with hammer but I got ignored. Question is can it be damaged with that type of hit? or maybe it was just coincidence? or maybe my cv joint was a bit fragile and the hammer hit end it?
(My father took it to a mechanic and in fact cv joint is bad. Only the tire that got hit not the other one or ones. He just didn't ask if the hammer could cause the break.)

No, I think it's impossible to hurt a CV joint by hitting a tire or wheel with a rubber hammer unless it's a giant hammer the size of a garbage can swung by the Incredible Hulk.
Daily, normal driving creates forces and impacts on the tires and wheels far greater than any blow from a rubber hammer that a mere human could make. These forces don't damage CV joints.
I believe this is just an unfortunate coincidence that the CV joint should fail as soon as you got new tires. Any working mechanic can tell you stories of how they were blamed for problems that really, really had no connection with the work they performed. Coincidences do happen!
